# Ignore desktop.ini files in all subdirectories [GitHub]

Tags: windows, git, github, gitignore

I have a folder that sync with google drive. So every folder and subfolder have a desktop.ini file.

I'm trying to make Git (GitHub) to ignore this desktop.ini files by adding this:

```
**/desktop.ini

desktop.ini

**/*/desktop.ini
```

To my .gitignore file. I added them one by one, combined, etc, and nothing. How I ignore dekstop.ini files in all subdirectories of my project?

Comment: Are those files already committed?

Comment: @DaveZych No. Never commited those files.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps make use of the .git/info/exclude file to list all files that should be ignored.

It should work to exclude files such as desktop.ini However, it has the drawback that each member of the team will have to add the rule manually since it is not committed to the repo. Thus, other team members might eventually also commit the desktop.ini files if they are not careful

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know about this. Perhaps, i think the problem it's no the gitignore file. I think i'm having troubles with GitHub Client. I'll re-try and comeback to give more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below code to your `~/.gitconfig` by running the following command:

`vi ~/.gitconfig`

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/<username>/Desktop/git_ignore_files.txt
```

And put the following types in the file that you mentioned in the `[core]` file like mentioned below

> desktop.ini
>
> *.swp
>
> .DS_Store